# Determine order of version numbers in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm working with some software that wants to include a module, but only for versions greater than "2.1.3". The code being used breaks down at version "2.1.10", which is considered less than "2.1.3" in a string comparison. What's the most elegant way to compare the version numbers correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural first step is to split the version "numbers" into numeric components:

```
v1 = '2.1.10'.split('.').map(&:to_i) # [ 2, 1, 10 ]
v2 = '2.1.3'.split('.').map(&:to_i)  # [ 2, 1,  3 ]
```

Then note that [`Array#<=>`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) compares arrays element by element so you can use it to whip up a quick'n'dirty `<` implementation for arrays. You can use `<=>` to monkey patch `#<` and `#>` methods into Array or just do it inline:

```
if (v1 <=> v2) < 0
  # v1 < v2
elsif (v1 <=> v2) > 0
  # v1 > v2
else
  # v1 == v2
end
```

`<=>` is specified to return `-1`, `0`, or `+1` so you could use

```
if (v1 <=> v2) == -1
  # v1 < v2
elsif (v1 <=> v2) == 1
  # v1 > v2
else
  # v1 == v2
end
```

too; I prefer the first version as the `< 0` and `> 0` are more suggestive as to the intent.

You'd probably want to hide all that behind a method somewhere or maybe even monkey patch `String` to have a version comparing method.

The above also means that `2.1` is a lower version number than, say, `2.1.11` so you don't have to worry about having the same number of components.

I am assuming that you're working with versions whose components are decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries for comparing version numbers, one of which is contained within RubGems (which is part of the Ruby stdlib), however, for simple version numbers like the ones in your question, simply splitting the version string, converting it to numbers, and relying on the fact that arrays in Ruby are ordered lexicographically is enough:

```
v1 = '2.1.3'.split('.').map(&:to_i)
v2 = '2.1.10'.split('.').map(&:to_i)

v1 <=> v2
# => -1
```

Comment: Where are you getting your `<=` for arrays from? 2.2 gives me a NoMethodError when I `[6] <= [11]`. Array is not Comparable so it doesn't come from there.

Comment: @muistooshort: Whow. 10 years of Ruby and I never noticed that `Array` defines `<=>` but not `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [Versionomy Gem](https://dazuma.github.io/versionomy/) for tasks like this, especially because it also handles edge cases like RC, alpha and beta versions:

```
v1 = Versionomy.create(:major => 1, :minor => 3, :tiny => 2)
v2 = Versionomy.parse('1.4a3')
v3 = Versionomy.parse('1.4.0b2')

v2 > v1 # => true
v3 > v2 # => true
```

Comment: This gem looks good, but it's a large project and I'm reluctant to add dependencies for a single comparison operation.

Comment: Check your Gemfile.lock. Lots of gems depend on this gem. Perhaps you have it already in use.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

**Code**

```
class Version
  include Comparable

  attr_reader :v

  def initialize(v)
    @v = v
  end

  def <=>(ov)
    pad_size = [v.size, ov.v.size].max
    convert(pad_size) <=> ov.convert(pad_size)
  end

  def convert(pad_size)
    v.gsub(/(^|\.)(\d+)/) { "#{$1}#{$2.rjust(pad_size,'0')}#{$3}" }
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
v0 = Version.new("2.1.02.3")
  #=> #<Version:0x007ff36a1055d0 @v="2.1.23.3"> 
v1 = Version.new("10.9.4.22")
  #=> #<Version:0x007ff36988fea0 @v="10.9.4.22">     
v2 = Version.new("1.11.4.1")
  #=> #<Version:0x007ff369875b18 @v="1.11.4.1"> 
v3 = Version.new("10.9.4.22")
  #=> #<Version:0x007ff369864570 @v="10.9.4.22"> 

v0 <=> v1 #=> -1 
v0 <=> v2 #=>  1 
v1 <=> v2 #=>  1 
v1 <=> v3 #=>  0 

v0 < v1   #=> true

[v0, v1, v2, v3].sort
  #=> [#<Version:0x007ff36996ba68 @v="1.11.4.1">,
  #    #<Version:0x007ff369990868 @v="2.1.02.3">,
  #    #<Version:0x007ff36997b418 @v="10.9.4.22">,
  #    #<Version:0x007ff369952838 @v="10.9.4.22">]
```

`v0 < v1` depends on `include Comparable` being present. (See μ's comment.)

**Explanation**

```
v0 = Version.new("2.1.02.3")
v1 = Version.new("10.9.4.22")

pad_size = [v0.v.size, v1.v.size].max
  #=> [8, 9].max => 9

v0.convert(9)
  #=> "000000002.000000001.000000002.000000003" 
v1.convert(9)
  #=> "000000010.000000009.000000004.000000022"
```

Therefore, `v0 <=> v1 #=> -1`.

Comment: Might want to [`include Comparable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Comparable.html) so that you can say `v0 < v1` and such for free.

Answer (score -3):

As I was writing up the question above I came up with the following:

```
"2.1.10".split('.')[0,3].join('').to_i >= "2.1.3".split('.')[0,3].join('').to_i
```

splitting and rejoining allows to limit to the first three places, as there is an optional fourth place used for descriptive strings

Comment: be careful since this logic will return version 0.10.1 is bigger than 1.0.0

Answer (score -4):

Try this at the beginning:

```
if RUBY_VERSION <= '2.1.3'<br>
  puts("Upgrade to version newer than 2.1.3")<br>
end
```